# Change the format in the paginage_links

Tags: pagination

I have created a FAQs section on my site that it has been paginated with the paginated_links WP routine. 
I'm not sure what is the reason, but as soon as I want to change the format parameter from page to something different, at the time a page greater than 1 is hit, WP redirects the browser to the home page. 
This is the code I use

```
       if( get_query_var('p') ) {
            $current = get_query_var( 'p' );
        } else {
            $current = 1;
        }

    $paginate_links = paginate_links( array(
        'base'      => '%_%',
        'mid_size'  => 5,
        'format'    => '?p=%#%',
        'current'   => $current,
        'total'     => $total
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

`p` is the post ID query var, `paged` or `page` are the pagination query vars, depending on the context.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't tell me how to change the name. Have you a ref I can read to learn_

Comment: change the name of what? the format should be `paged` instead of `p`.

Comment: paged or page results in a querystring parameter called page. I'd like it to be "p", or something one char. Is this possible?

Comment: No, you can't use `p`, WordPress already uses that for post IDs. You could possibly use another single character, but then you'd have to hook pre_get_posts and convert your custom pagination query var to set the correct one.